# Wordpress - get_terms() returns "invalid taxonomy" (this is not a hook issue)

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

On my local machine it works fine, but on the live server, when I run

```
get_terms('taxonomy' => 'any_taxonomy');
```

it returns a list of terms, but if I add any parameter to it like:

```
get_terms('taxonomy' => 'any_taxonomy','hide_empty' => false);
```

Then it returns "invalid taxonomy". The issue is not that the taxonomy is not registerd get_taxonomies() before it, it shows that all the taxonomies are registered. If I do this:

```
    get_terms('taxonomy' => 'category','hide_empty' => false);
```

The same problem is there, so its not just custom taxonomies.

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Can anyone suggest a way to diagnose this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i'd say you are running different versions of wordpress, 4.5 changed the functionality of `get_terms()`

```
 get_terms(  array('taxonomy' => 'any_taxonomy','hide_empty' => false) );
```

Should work, but i also think if you are calling `get_terms()` before registering your taxonomy is going to cause issues.

Comment: The taxonomies are registered. It works on the local machine, just not on the live server. Also, I can get the terms for any taxonomy if there are no parameters added. Can anyone suggest a way to diagnose this?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/ - Upgrade WP on the remote server and everything should work. Pre-4.5 it will try to fetch the hide_empty taxonomy because the first parameter was the list of taxonomies.

Comment: john as @gant says the way the function works has changed between wp versions, I suggest you update wordpress and try the above, there is no other explanation unless you have modified the core files.  please accept answer and upvote if it has helped.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right it was an issue with wordpress versions. The live server had an older version of wordpress running.