# WP get_terms() returns error on admin side

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

This one might be a simple question, but it's driving me nuts :)

I'm trying to make an admin settings page on the `wp-admin` side for which I need to get all the values of a certain category.

This is part of my test code:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'my-category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($terms);
echo '</pre>';
```

But this returns an error. Something like `"invalid taxonomy"`.
When I leave the `'taxonomy'` arg from `get_terms()` it returns all the terms successfully. ( but of course I need to filter it by my tax term.

Anyone knows what's up? :)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
get_terms(  array('taxonomy' => 'any_taxonomy','hide_empty' => false) );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. That's the same code I have :) Or am I mistaken.

Comment: Okay, Please see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898313/wordpress-get-terms-returns-invalid-taxonomy-this-is-not-a-hook-issue

Comment: That's also not the case I'm afraid. This goes for WP pre-4.5. And I'm currently running 4.9.8.

Comment: Hey Please see this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13480/get-terms-return-errors

Comment: Yes! That's it. The first answer gave me the "why" and the second the solution. Thanks @gufran

Comment: this one https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13480/get-terms-return-errors?

Comment: @Tim, great :) enjoy